# Problem: How to display a Wordpress RSS feed in a browser that doesn't have a built in RSS reader?

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, rss

*If I can, i'd rather not use a service like FeedBurner.*

**My setup:**

I've setup a RSS feed link on a self-hosted Wordpress website, clicking the RSS link in Safari shows the feed - because Safari has a built in RSS reader. Great.

Unfortunately clicking the same RSS link in Chrome displays the raw XML feed. I know why this happens - Chrome doesn't have a built in RSS reader. I also assume this will be the same in  older versions of Internet Explorer.

**Possible solution?**

I've noticed http://www.bbc.co.uk/news has a nice solution:

Click the RSS feed (top tight of the page) in a RSS enabled browser (Safari) and it uses the built in RSS reader to display the RSS feed.

Click the same RSS feed link in Chrome (Chrome has no built in RSS reader) it displays the RSS feed using what looks like a custom page.

Is there a way to check if a browser has a built in RSS reader?

How would I provide alternative content (like the BBC site) to a browser that doesn't have a RSS reader installed?

Any help on this would be brilliant, thanks for taking the time to read this.
Stephen

Comment: Thanks to Ceejayoz for pointing me in this direction. I've found a handy article on the subject... Trying it out now:http://osric.com/chris/accidental-developer/2008/12/create-an-xsl-stylesheet-for-your-rss-or-atom-feeds/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just look at the source code of the [BBC's feed](http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml). It's all the same stuff - they just have an XSL stylesheet (which Safari ignores).

http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/shared/bsp/xsl/rss/nolsol.xsl

That stylesheet contains instructions on generating the friendly display you see in Chrome.

(this is, incidentally, how Feedburner does it, too)

Comment: Thanks Rochester, Matt and ceejayoz. The Stack Overflow community is brilliant :

Comment: how would I add a XSL stylesheet to a RSS feed?

Comment: Again, look at the source code. It's all in there. `<?xml-stylesheet title="XSL_formatting" type="text/xsl" href="/shared/bsp/xsl/rss/nolsol.xsl"?>`

Comment: Can anyone recommend a good tutorial on creating a xml document to display a RSS feed and style it with a .xsl stylesheet. Can't seem to find anything...

Comment: Why not use the BBC's one as a starting point? It's reasonably straightforward stuff.

Comment: I'll have another look at it over the weekend. I couldn't figure out a way to link the feed with the .xml file. I'm going to get to the bottom of this! :)

Comment: View the feed's source in Chrome (not Safari, you'll just see the Safari-generated feedreader stuff there) and look for the line that references the .xsl file. Very simple.

Comment: I couldn't get this solution to work until I started serving my feed with a `Content-Type: text/xml` header instead of the standard RSS one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use jQuery to check browser's version, and then redirect to the normal RSS feed, OR redirect to a page using a feed reader plugin, like zrssfeed ( http://www.zazar.net/developers/zrssfeed/ ).

But, you will have to do a little reasearch about waht browsers supports RSS to do the redirect! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would route your feed through [Feedburner](http://feedburner.google.com). As well as giving you handy subscriber stats, you can also turn on their "BrowserFriendly" setting -- this should give your readers a pleasant experience in both Chrome and other browsers.

I didn't actually mean for that to sound like a soap powder ad, and I have no marketing affiliation to Google or Feedburner, by the way :)